# Using Deferred in React.js or callback in my success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I have a React/ Flux app I am trying to return my "promiseSuccessData" but it has to be done outside of the ajax promise. Within the getChallengeData().

```
getChallengeData : function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl + '1.0/challenge/result/' + challengeId,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields : {
            withCredentials : true
        },
    })
    .done(function(promiseSuccessData) {
        _challenges = promiseSuccessData;
    })
    .fail(function(jqXhr) {
        console.log(jqXhr)
        console.log('failed to register');
    });
    //This is where I want to "return _challenges" but _challenges isn't available here
},
```

Comment: you probably want to return the promise from here and call `.done` in the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the promise instead, and add the done handler outside where you need to use the value (I will assume that `getChallengeData` is a method of an object called `myObj` for the sake of the example):

```
getChallengeData : function() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl + '1.0/challenge/result/' + challengeId,
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields : {
            withCredentials : true
        },
    }).fail(function(jqXhr) {
        console.log(jqXhr)
        console.log('failed to register');
    });
},
```

And then, when you use it:

```
myObj.getChallengeData().done(function(promiseSuccessData) {
    _challenges = promiseSuccessData;
    //do something with challenges.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Saw that the OP wanted to return the value of `_challenges`, not just work with it somehow.

You can't work with `_challenges` until the `done` function has run.  When working with asynchronous Promises, you'll want to return the actual Promise (jQuery Deferred?) and have the caller attach his own handler.

```
function foo() {
    obj.getChallengeData()
        .done(function(challenges) {
            // Work with challenges here
        });
}

var obj = {
    getChallengeData : function() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + '1.0/challenge/result/' + challengeId,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields : {
                withCredentials : true
            },
        })
        .fail(function(jqXhr) {
            console.log(jqXhr)
            console.log('failed to register');
        });
    },
    // Other props
}
```

Comment: Aww downvoted before my edit.

Comment: balancing out the down vote b/c edited answer doesnt deserve it, however you still haven't addressed how getChallengeData would return the promise ;)

Comment: @pherris Too true.  Editor here I come!